# While hosting web application on IIS, getting External table is not in expected format

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="Excel03ConString"
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};
                         Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"/>
    <add name ="Excel07ConString"
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};
                         Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR={1}'"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

```
string conStr = "";
string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FilePath);
switch (Extension)
{
    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
        conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"]
                 .ConnectionString;
        break;
    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
        conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"]
                  .ConnectionString;
        break;
}
conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
```

I'm uploading an Excel and importing the data to a data table.I have another excel which is kind of a default data and the data is being compared with the uploaded excel data to extract the results but the problem is it's giving "External table is not in expected format error" and there is no specific pattern. Sometime the application will run just fine, without any error and sometime in the middle of processing, it will through this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the issue was that i forgot to close the connection. I know its a silly mistake but if you are getting this error better check if all the connections are closed and all objects are properly disposed. thanks